# Changing the interface language in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, language, user-interface

A friend of mine has recently purchased a laptop in the U.S. that has Windows 7 Home Premium on it with an English interface. Not being a native English speaker, I'm trying to change the interface language to traditional Chinese.

I've looked through the Control Panel in search of something that might let me change the interface language. Naturally, I looked at the Region and Language section and managed to change the formats the computer uses and install a working keyboard, but I haven't found a way to change the interface language.

Upon doing some research, I found out that there are two kinds of interface packs, Multilingual User Interface (MUI) and Language Interface Packs (LIP).

It seems that MUIs can only be installed through Windows Update, so I looked through the list of updates. To my dismay, the language packs are not present. The optional updates tab doesn't even show up. Many sites show a drop down menu the under Keyboards and Languages tab in the Region and Language options, yet it doesn't show up for me. We also don't have the Windows 7 DVD which might contain this useful file.

As far as the LIPs go, I can't find one in Chinese at all, let alone traditional Chinese.

Can the interface language be changed in Home Premium at all? If it can, how would I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/springboard/archive/2009/08/25/windows-7-language-packs-available.aspx

> These language packs are available to our enterprise customers running Windows 7 Enterprise and Windows 7 Ultimate RTM versions only.

Comment: So that's a no?

Comment: Yes, that is a "no". You need Ultimate or Enterprise edition.