# Changing the interface language on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, language

There have been many threads about this but my case is rather tricky. I have bought a new PC, the person who assembled the PC has installed a Windows 7 Professional Polish starter pack. The day after I bought the PC I have bought the Windows 7 Pro (OEM) English. I typed in the activation codes and it has been fully registered.

I decided that I have to change the language to English so I went to Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region settings > Changed the Format from "Polski" to "English (United States)" and it has only changed the way my date is displayed.

What can I do, there are two options I see, but I don't really like them

> Use the Vistalizator~ http://www.froggie.sk/usage.html
>
> Use the CD to format OS partition, I do not have a CD/DVD-ROM on that PC, so it would be a bit more problematic for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Windows 7 are you using exactly? The reason I ask this is because Windows 7 Starter does not officially support language packs. There is no such thing as `Windows 7 Professional Starter`. Possible duplicate questions: http://superuser.com/questions/245663/how-do-i-change-languages-in-windows-7-starter-edition?rq=1 http://superuser.com/questions/77166/can-i-change-windows-7-display-language-on-home-premium-version?rq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/97661/changing-the-interface-language-in-windows-7-home-premium?rq=1

Comment: The person who assambled has installed the POLISH Windows 7 Professional OEM, I had a month to activate it.

Comment: I attempte dto clarify the title.  There isn't a "Starter Pack" to my knowlege.  There might be a trial but that is something very different.  Windows 7 Professional does not support language packs.  You would have to reinstall Windows 7 using an English installation if you want an English interface.

Comment: Yes! I have activated it, with the Windows 7 Pro. English OEM.

Comment: Here is a possible duplicate question: http://superuser.com/questions/590747/how-change-windows-language-from-spanish-to-english-in-a-windows-7-professionals with a workaround answer.

Comment: Why are you going to close the question?

Comment: Because it is a duplicate I will flag it*